# Adding fadein() effect handlers to a switch background-image function in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(spinna, 3000);


var index = 0,
   imgs = ['bg2.jpg', 'scrib.jpg'];
function spinna(){

      console.log(imgs[index]);
      $('#header_bg').fadeIn('slow',function(){
      $('#header_bg').css({   
        'background-image' : 'url(' + '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/'+ imgs[index] +'' + ')'            
      });  
   });          
    index == 0 ? index = 1 : index = 0;       
 }   
});
```

Live Code
http://gmcfosho.com/

Where am I going wrong in this code?

Any help on this would be most helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solutions.  Somewhat taken from the comments to OP.  I used a plugin called flexslider and used it as a mask.  Here is the sample code on how to implement.

http://www.designobvio.us/flex

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use a plugin like Cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
Check out the "scrollRight" effect.

Comment: I must use Background image not inline images.

Comment: Instead of having one html element and rotate the BG image you could have multiple elements and use Cycle. You will not be able to do the transition you want while changing the background image on a single element. You have to use multiple elements if you want to animate two images at the same time. I assume that when you said "I would like the image to slide in from the right and old image to slide out from the left" that you want this to be simultaneous.

Comment: what about a simple fadein/fadeout?  I can see why slidein/out can cause trouble now.  I just dont understand semantically where the effect would go.

Comment: You can't fade in one background image and out another on the same element. If you want two animations at once then you need two elements. If you want to see what the markup should be then inspect element on the examples in the link I provided. In the end all it is is a div with a bunch of images in it but the elements you use really don't matter much.

Comment: View source on this for a simple example: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html